# Send a interaction message to a Discord Bot with Python

Tags: python, discord

I want to interact with another discord bot.

For example, I would like to trigger MEE6's `/help` in a specific channel.
I know how to send normal messages via the requests library in python, but they don't trigger the commands of discord bots.
Example: If I send a normal message with the content "/help" via python requests in a channel, the MEE6 Bot wont respond to this message.

For sending a normal message, I used the code below.
Is there a way to send an interaction in a similar way?

```
header = {'authorization' : Token}
payload = {'content' = 'command'}
r = requests.post(ServerID, data=payload, headers=header)
```